# My motherboard has a 24 pin power connector, but my PSU only has a 20 pin connector. Will it work without an adapter?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible (and safe/reliable/non-damaging) to use a 20-pin ATX PSU with a 24-pin ATX motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/13332/is-it-possible-and-safe-reliable-non-damaging-to-use-a-20-pin-atx-psu-with-a-24)

So the power supply (I hope) went on one of my computers during an electrical storm recently, and the computer won't start.  I have an old PSU, but unfortunately it only has a 20 pin connector, and my motherboard has a 24 pin header.  I don't need the system to run, I just need it to POST.  After I determine that it isn't the motherboard that has died, I can pick up an adapter.  What I need to know is will it even get that far without the adapter?  I'd rather not pull a PSU from one of my other computers just for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is *possible*, but ***not recommended***. It is better to buy a 20 to 24-pin adapter to avoid power problems with PCI-e cards that do not have their own power connector. See below diagram, make sure it's all the way to the right:

[image]

Comment: Fortunately, the good folks behind the ATX standard actually keyed the connectors so it would be impossible to plug the 20-pin into the 24-pin the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, I will be buying an adapter in the coming days.  As far as PCIe goes, all I have in there is a nVidia 7600GT (or GS, I forget).  Nothing too power hungry.