# Connecting 20 pin power supply to a 24 pin board

Tags: power-supply

I have scoured the web and unable to find a manual for my board telling me how I should hook up my new power supply.

- **PC:** Gateway GT5628
- **Board:** Intel Desktop Board DG33SXG2
- **Original Power Supply:** Generic 400w w/ 24 pin connector
- **Replacement Power Supply:** Antec Basiq 500w w/ 20 pin connector + 4 pin

I was reading on a forum that the manufacturer of the board should specify in the manual whether or not to use the +4, however I cannot find documentation on Intel or Gateway's support portals for this board. *(Gateway has support docs but nothing referring to the power supply)*

Since the original was 24 should I just plug the 20 furthest to the right and add the +4 on the left, or should I leave the +4 unplugged?

*Update*

I was able to find the [Antec manual](http://www.antec.com/pdf/manuals/BP500U_manual_EN.pdf) so I can see which side to add the +4 to, I just wanted to make sure of that because it looked like it could go on either side. At this point I'm assuming since there was a 24 in before I should connect this accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer: if the additional 4-pin ATX extension connector is available, then you should be using it. :)

Related information is also available in this SU question: [Is it possible (and safe/reliable/non-damaging) to use a 20-pin ATX PSU with a 24-pin ATX motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/13332/is-it-possible-and-safe-reliable-non-damaging-to-use-a-20-pin-atx-psu-with-a-2)

Answer (score 1):

The new power supply lists as 20+4 because its backwards compatible with 20 pin boards. If you notice, the 4 pin connector will seat into the 20 pin to make a solid 24 pin connector.

Also, the pins are keyed so they only fit in easily one direction. If it doesnt seem to fit in a given configuration, change it around until it slides in easy. notice the shapes on some of the pins are different. Just line them up.